# Increase max_user_connections for ClearDB MySQL on Windows Azure Website

Tags: mysql, azure

Currently, **Windows Azure Websites** with a **MySQL** database from **ClearDB** appear to have a `max_user_connections` limit of 4. This seems silly. You can scale up multiple instances of **Large** servers ( 4 cores, 7GB memory ), but what's the point? Your bottleneck will almost always be max_user_connections if it's set to a **pitiful value of 4**. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't use Azure and cleardb, but when I check cleardb web site, I see that up to 4 user is on free plan. maybe you need to get a higher plan?

https://www.cleardb.com/store/azure

```
mercury plan: Connections up to 4 (free)
venus plan: Connections up to 15
saturn plan: Connections up to 30
jupiter plan: Connections up to 40
```

Comment: This isn't a solution necessarily, but it would appear to be an explanation of why `max_user_connections = 4`. +1 for that. :)

There doesn't seem to be a clear way to change ClearDB plans within Azure Websites. I spoke with the Azure team yesterday and they did mention database scaling was possible, but I believe it would need to be requested on their end.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since it led directly to a usable solution. :)

I upgraded the ClearDB MySQL database to the Venus plan and noticed a **dramatic** performance increase in addition to getting 15 concurrent connections now.

Comment: Is it just me or does even the highest tier plan (40 connections) seem very limiting?

Comment: I'm running a wordpress instance on azure connected to SQL Azure database, and over the last 24 hours my max connections hit 61.  The mysql limits are way too small, although we will be contacting cleardb to inquire about an enterprise plan.  Space isn't a big issue, but the connection limits are deal killers.  SQL Server causes other problems with wordpress (plugins that don't work, mostly).

Comment: **Clear DB** is just too expensive right now, in my opinion. I actually prefer creating my own Linux VMs on azure to host my databases. If you need high scalability, use **HyperDB**. :)